# Move ACF Field to another page & transfer data

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields on a website.  I made a field group named "About".  In this field group I had many fields including a repeater for "Board Members".  I've decided to show board members on its own page instead of on the main About page.  As a result, I want the board member fields to appear when editing the "Board Members" page instead of the "About" page.

Moving the fields from one field group to another is not a problem.  ACF has this ability built in.  The problem is that when I move fields from one field group to another, the data I had entered into those fields doesn't transfer over.

I've contacted ACF directly about this but I'm still struggling to get this to work and I'm hoping someone here has done this before and can explain how to do it without getting into the backend and manually editing the database (I don't have access).

I have to assume that the data is stored with the page ID it was attached to, and now because the page ID has changed it doesn't show the data.  Does anyone know of an easy solution to this problem?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know of a solution, but with content like that, it's easier to build out members as a custom post type so you can feed into whatever page you need.

Comment: Good point.  I'm currently doing that with Partners.  Perhaps I should just do that with Board Members too just to avoid this.  Thanks.